# How to enable mod_deflate and mod_pagespeed on a php heroku app on the cedar stack?

Tags: php, apache, heroku, mod-pagespeed, mod-deflate

I am lost in trying to figure out how to enable mod_deflate and mod_pagespeed on my php app hosted on heroics' cedar stack. I can't find anything about doing so online and what I have found is either outdated or unhelpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but it looks like you'd have to set up a web server (Apache or Nginx) with PageSpeed installed and tell Cedar to reverse proxy to your server.  Then you would have your server reverse proxy to your php app.

Cedar is based off Nginx, so it could run ngx_pagespeed, but it currently doesn't.